# MySQL workbench: Can't connect to server on work pc

Tags: mysql, server

I am trying to run a mysql server on my work pc but it won't let me run it. Hostname is localhost and port is 3306 with root as username and no password.

I am thinking there is something wrong as this is running on the computer but I am connected to it with my work account. 
[image]
How to configure the server?

Comment: is mysql itself running?

Comment: Ensure `mysqld.exe` is running.

Comment: Is MySQL installed properly? Dependencies and all.

Comment: Start it using the Terminal and see what it prints. It's probably a misconfiguration that's shutting it down before it starts properly.